# How to solve the compatibility problem of "crossorigin" attribute in <script /> on iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, compatibility

The crossorigin attribute in <script /> is not compatible on iOS, and the specific error message cannot be captured, only "Script Error" can be seen. How to solve it so that it can report a specific error message?
[error messages in monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fegxq.png)
[crossorigin compatibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWGJR.jpg)

```
<script src="https://xxx/test.js" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
```

Because iOS does not support "crossorigin", the current error message is as follows:
[script error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rtQg.png)
Need to make it like this:
[specific error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R3DE.png)

There is very little information that can be found, and there is no solution that can solve this problem.